# Will ConnectWise work on Ubuntu?

Tags: remote-login

Will ConnectWise work on Ubuntu 20.10? I downloaded a file called 'ConnectWiseControl.Client.jnlp' but I don't know how to run it as it's a text file.

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a Java Network Launch Protocol file. You need to install Iced Tea, which can run JNLP files.

Open a terminal and run the following command

```
sudo apt install icedtea-netx icedtea-plugin
```

Double-click the .jnlp file to run it.

Comment: I did that and got the error 'unable to locate the package icedtea-plugin.

Comment: Try just `sudo apt install icedtea-netx`

Comment: Thanks. Yes I forgot the 'apt'

Comment: @asharpham If that's solved your problem, then please accept the answer - this will help other people that might have the same question.

Comment: Is there a standard way to accept the answer?

Comment: @asharpham There's a greyed out tick symbol to the left of the answer - click that, and it should go green.